# How to select rows based on 2 columns?

Tags: r

```
dx <- data.frame(CMPD = c("cmpd1","cmpd1","cmpd1","cmpd1","cmpd2","cmpd2",
                          "cmpd2","cmpd2","cmpd3","cmpd3","cmpd3","cmpd3"),
                 MRM = c("309.0/121.1","309.0/121.1","309.0/90.1",
                         "309.0/90.1","305.2/140.3","305.2/140.3","300.5/107.3",
                         "300.5/107.3","404.8/126.0","404.8/126.0","401.5/91.0",
                         "401.5/91.0"),
                 RESP = c(123.4,234.5,345.6,456.7,567.8,678.9,789.0,12.4,
                          23.5,34.6,45.7,56.8))
```

-

```
>dx

CMPD         MRM  RESP

1  cmpd1 309.0/121.1 123.4
2  cmpd1 309.0/121.1 234.5
3  cmpd1  309.0/90.1 345.6
4  cmpd1  309.0/90.1 456.7
5  cmpd2 305.2/140.3 567.8
6  cmpd2 305.2/140.3 678.9
7  cmpd2 300.5/107.3 789.0
8  cmpd2 300.5/107.3  12.4
9  cmpd3 404.8/126.0  23.5
10 cmpd3 404.8/126.0  34.6
11 cmpd3  401.5/91.0  45.7
12 cmpd3  401.5/91.0  56.8
```

I would like to be able to work with this data based on the uniqueness of the combination of `CMPD` and `MRM` (e.g. rows 1, 2 then rows 3, 4 etc.)

Comment: "Work with"? Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: let's say I just want to get an average or a ratio of the RESP column for those selected rows. It could be any FUNC though. The question is really about how to select just those rows with unique "CMPD - MRM" combinations. I will need to loop through these and perform the same 'work' on each set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process entire subsets of the data frame, the common thing to do is to use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(dx, .(CMPD, MRM), .fun = doStuff)
```

Alternatives are `ave` or `by` and `aggregate`. For the specific example of calculating the ratio, using `summarise` can help a lot:

```
ddply(dx, .(CMPD, MRM), .fun = summarise, ratio = RESP[1]/RESP[2])
```

This type of task is commonly referred to as 'split-apply-combine' in the R world.

Answer (score 5):

Let me introduce you to my friend, the package `plyr`.

This package makes it easy to use a generic strategy of splitting,applying and combining data. One of the most useful functions is `ddply` which takes a data frame as input and reduces a data frame as output. You specify the unique combinations to split by, as well as the function you want to apply, and `ddply` does the rest.

A good place to learn about `plyr` is [Hadley's website](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) or [his article in the Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).  There are also hundreds of answers about plyr on StackOverflow.  Just follow the [plyr](/questions/tagged/plyr)-tag or the [ddply](/questions/tagged/ddply)-tag.

Here are some examples:

```
library(plyr)
```

To extract the mean:

```
> ddply(dx, .(CMPD, MRM), numcolwise(mean))
   CMPD         MRM   RESP
1 cmpd1 309.0/121.1 178.95
2 cmpd1  309.0/90.1 401.15
3 cmpd2 300.5/107.3 400.70
4 cmpd2 305.2/140.3 623.35
5 cmpd3  401.5/91.0  51.25
6 cmpd3 404.8/126.0  29.05
```

Or the sum:

```
> ddply(dx, .(CMPD, MRM), numcolwise(sum))
   CMPD         MRM   RESP
1 cmpd1 309.0/121.1  357.9
2 cmpd1  309.0/90.1  802.3
3 cmpd2 300.5/107.3  801.4
4 cmpd2 305.2/140.3 1246.7
5 cmpd3  401.5/91.0  102.5
6 cmpd3 404.8/126.0   58.1
```

Comment: [I think this is what you meant to say](http://www.redmolotov.com/images/designs/sayhello_design.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `by` function

```
by(dx$RESP, list(CMPD = dx$CMPD, MRM = dx$MRM), mean)
```

It returns a `by` object which is not necessarily easy to "work with", but it is possible.